# Is there a way to check the serial number of my MacBook motherboard that shipped with my MacBook, with the Macbook's serial number?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, motherboard

Is there a way to check the serial number of my MacBook motherboard that shipped with my MacBook if I have the machine serial number? I'd like to check if a 3rd-party repair shop swapped out my motherboard. (so I can't be sure that the serial number of the motherboard that is currently in my Macbook is indeed the one that originally came with it)

Or is the motherboard serial number the same as the Macbook's (I have not opened any Macbook before so I do not know this.)

Comment: Do you think they might have charged you for swapping the board but not done it, or do you think they swapped the boards secretly for some reason?

Comment: @benwiggy swapped secretly for some reason ;(

Answer (score 1):

My experience when I had the motherboard replaced in a 2016 MacBook is that the motherboard does not have a separate serial number. When a motherboard is replaced, the MacBook's serial number is zapped into the replacement motherboard. In my case, the repairer forgot to do that so it came back without serial number (except that etched onto the case) and I had to return the MacBook for the serial number to be zapped onto the motherboard.

So, if the motherboard has been replaced and the repairer has done things correctly, you can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Click Apple logo on top left of MacBook screen > About this Mac. From the Info window, copy the serial number. Go to this [website](http://www.chipmunk.nl/cgi-fast/applemodel.cgi) and paste the serial number in the search bar. Submit, then scroll down to see all the details about your Mac, including the motherboard number. Is this what you need?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any part serials for my Mac there: just basic info about the CPU, RAM, production dates, etc.

Comment: Added screenshot. Motherboard number can be found in it.

Comment: That is a part number for the motherboard. The question is about serial number.

Comment: @MacEater I have tried this, but it states that my motherboard number is unknown for this Serial Number.. ;(;( Where does this site get all its data from?

Comment: @forgodsakehold must be from some plist, not sure. Will update if I find out.